# sqlalchemy relationship through an intermediate table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, relationship

I have three related classes: Parent, Child, SubChild.  The relationship is one-many in both cases.  I've set it up so `child.parent` references correctly and of course so that `sub_child.child.parent` works as well.

The thing is that I never actually need to know `sub_child.child`, but I do need to know the sub_child's ultimate parent.  I'd like to set up a relationship such that `sub_child.parent` would return a reference to the ultimate Parent object.

Is this possible, or is it just a bad idea?  I've read the documentation, but don't see much that looks promising.

I'm using python2 and sqlalchemy orm on mysql as a backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html

With this method you should be able to create a mapping over the three tables you mentioned and assign the columns of the participating tables as attributes to the mapping class.

```
metadata = MetaData()

parent = Table('parent', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('child', Integer, ForeignKey('child.id')),
)
child = Table('child', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('subchild', Integer, ForeignKey('subchild.id')),
)
subchild = Table('subchild', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('some_column', String),
)
joined = join(parent, child, subchild)

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __table__ = joined

    id = column_property(parent.c.id, child.c.id, subchild.c.id)
    subchild_attr = subchild.c.some_column
```

Comment: interesting - does this offload the lookup to the database, or is it handled in the ORM layer?  As an alternative, I was looking at defining some simple getter functions on the class.

Comment: Yes a query with this mapper will join all three tables without further efforts. Of  course you  can also "pull up" the nested  columns with '@property' but you have to use query options like 'joinedload' in order to avoid subsequent queries. If you go for the getter version, have a look at the '@hybrid_property' decorator.